# Elegant mechanism to determine smallest magnitude number but preserve sign in Python

Tags: python, math

I have a Pythonic need to determine the minimum number in terms of absolute value, but preserve its sign.  Below is the code I use to do this now.   Is there a more elegant mechanism either mathematically or pythonically?  This function is one of the most used functions in my application, so it would be nice if it were as efficient as possible in terms of interpretive overhead and mathematical calculation.

```
def minmag(*l):
    la=map(abs,l) #store magnitudes
    v=min(map(abs,l)) #find minimum magnitude
    return math.copysign(v,l[la.index(v)]) #put the sign back

print minmag(5,10) #prints 5
print minmag(-5,-10) #prints -5
print minmag(-5,-10,10,-2,-1) #prints -1
```

P.S. I don't care which sign is presented when there are ties in terms of equal magnitude.

Comment: Make several variants, and benchmark them with typical argument counts? I'm not sure a lot of people know the interpretive overhead of looping vs. list copies off the top of their heads.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `key` named parameter of `min`:

```
>>> min(-5, -10, 10, -2, -1, key=abs)
-1
```

See also: [documentation for the built-in function `min`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min).

Comment: This is great.  For those encountering this answer, `key` is the function min uses to identify the relative order of elements.  By passing `abs` you're saying to order based on magnitude, not size, yet the element itself retains its original value.